# Problem while compiling using make when i include the cs50 library?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, clang, cs50

I have installed the **CS50 library**
in **Ubuntu 20.04**
This code is just to see if it works
It works without any problem with clang
But when using make it does not automatically link the library so I get this error -
i'm using visual studio code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    string d = get_string("what is your name: ");
    printf("Hello, %s\n ",d);
}
```

**outbut**

```
mohamed@mohamed-Latitude-E5470:~/Downloads/projects$ clang hello.c -o hello -lcs50
mohamed@mohamed-Latitude-E5470:~/Downloads/projects$ make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccJDbREo.o: in function `main':
hello.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `get_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: hello] Error 1
```

how to make it automatically link the library when using **make**

Comment: To use `make` outside CS50 environment you have to create `makefile` file in your project directory and specify some rules in it ,read more about makefiles,[how to makefiles](https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html) maybe helpfull